# Unexpected identifier when importing express

Tags: node.js, express, package.json

I am new to js and also node.js. I get unexpected identifier error when I try to start the server with the "nodemon server.js" command. express is installed.
Here is the server.js file:

```
import express  from   'express' ; 
import mongoose from 'mongoose' ;


const app = express();
const port = proces.env.PORT || 8001 




app.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).send("hello ozzy") ); 


// Listener
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on localhost: ${port}`));
```

and here is my package.json file:

```
{
 "name": "bookvisor-backend",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "server.js",
 "type": "module",
 "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "nodemon server.js"
},
"author": "ozan",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.17.1",
  "mongoose": "^5.11.18"
},
"devDependencies":{
  "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
 }
}
```

Here the error message

```
import express  from   'express' ; 
   ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

i think you already found the solution, but for someone who might have this problem, i had exact the same issue and i did everything nothing worked and also i had the problem with mongoose that thrown me an error saying TextEncoder not found, but when i updated NODE and NPM, all the errors gone.

**EDIT**

**What problems did i have?**

- ES6 syntax was not applying even though i specified `"type": "module"` in  the `package.json`
- importing mongoose thrown an error `new TextEncoder() is not definned`

**What did i try?**

- removing and reinstalling all the packages. **Failed**
- deleting node modules and reinstalling it. **Failed**
- completely deleting project and recoding all again. **Failed**

**What was the solution?**

Just updating `npm` and `node` version. Ubuntu in my case,

node:

- `sudo npm cache clean -f`
- `sudo npm install -g n`
- `sudo n stable`

npm:

- `sudo npm install -g npm`

Comment: You should add the exact command to reach your solution. This would make your answer easy understood.

Answer (score 0):

try only **nodemon** or **nodemon --exec npm start** or upload the message error

Answer (score 0):

You should install nodemon as a dev dependancy

For example

npm install nodemon —save-dev

After that package.json file should look like that

In scripts section do the following

```
“Start” : “nodemon my_file.js”
```

Then in command line window write

```
npm start
```

Comment: did whole steps but did not work. Now I will edit the question with adding error message and package.json again

Comment: Remove node server. Js in start to nodemon server. Js

Comment: You have to install node mon as dev depandancy.  npm install nodemon - - save-dev

Comment: yeah i already did that package.json must be correct rn.

Comment: Start in script in package json change to nodemon server.js

Comment: OK. I did that as well. Seems that I forgot to  edit package.json. But error still remains :(  @Ahmed

Comment: There might be something wrong with the nodemon installation i guess.

Comment: Try npm i nodemon - g